# Getting index of kivy spinner selection

Tags: spinner, kivy

Usually the spinner widget returns the selected text. In my app i plan to use some non standard letters (like: ü,ö,è) as values to populate the spinner.
The below example works on my windows machine but I hope to avoid handling any Non-ASCII characters to prevent problems on other OS's.

Is there a way to access the index of the spinner selection directly without using the list.index(text) method?

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner


spinnervalues = ['one_ö','two_ü','three_ä']

spinner = Spinner(
    # default value shown
    text='Home',
    # available values
    values=spinnervalues,
    # just for positioning in our example
    size_hint=(None, None),
    size=(100, 44),
    pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5})

def show_selected_value(spinner, text):
    print('The spinner', spinner, 'have text', text)

    list_index = spinnervalues.index(text)
    print('This list item index:', list_index)

spinner.bind(text=show_selected_value)

runTouchApp(spinner)
```

I have tried something like:

```
 spinner.bind(index=show_selected_value)
```

but without success.

Comment: Python should handle unicode consistently across different OSs.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Seems like i can concentrate on other problems.

Answer (score 1):

I know this original question is very old now, but for future reference you could try:

```
    list_index = spinner.values.index(text)
    print('This list item index:', list_index)
```

which prints:

```
'This list item index:', 2
```

assuming you picked the 3rd item in the list of spinner.values (zero based index).

I use a similar construct in my code because the text (spinnervalues) may change based on the language in use.

And this ties the value back to current spinner object, incase you're using multiple spinners in your application.

hope that helps someone.